# Post-order Tree Walk without marking node?

Tags: algorithm

I saw a question which is asking designing algorithm for "Post-order Tree Walk without marking node".

What does this question mean?

Comment: Do you think you could post the link the question that prompted your question?

Comment: Are there pointers or references to the parent node available in each node?

Comment: I believe the question i question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412975/bin-tree-post-order-traversal-no-recursion-no-node-flag/3414478

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are generally 3 ways to visit nodes in a tree: pre-order, in-order, post-order.

Pre-order means you process the node before processing the children.

In-order means you process the the left children (assuming here that it is a binary tree), then the current node, then the right children.

Post-order means you process a node after processing both children.

"Processing a node" could by *any* operation on a node, as simple as writing the stored payload of the node to the console.

Doing it without marking means *not* using an indicator (usually an extra field in the node) to show that a node has been visited. As Peter G. mentioned, the indicator should not be needed with recursive implemenations.

Answer (score 0):

The standard recursive tree traversal algorithms need no marking of nodes. Marking or modification of nodes is only needed for constant space traversal algorithms.