# Designing of the asp.net website master page like another existing website?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, visual-studio-2008

I am designing a master page of a website, which i am designing in asp.net web forms. Like the website :

http://bayyinah.com/dream./

I have worked up some stuff and below is the image, of how my website really looks now :

[image]

i have to make a footer and a menu, using jquery like the one in http://bayyinah.com/dream./

And here is my html of master page :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="LeaveManagementSystemMasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="LeaveManagementSystemMasterPage" %>
```

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <title></title>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">

  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Menu.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
   <table style="width:100%;height:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <table width="100%" style="background-color: #202020">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/LeaveImage.PNG"/>
            </td>
            <td width="100%">
            </td>
        </tr>        
    </table>
              <%-- Provide header in the cell--%>
    </td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td>      
        <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="100%" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="10" CssClass="MenuBar">
            <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="StaticMenuItem" />
            <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="StaticMenuItemStyle" />
            <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="StaticHoverStyle" />
            <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="StaticSelectedStyle" />
            <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="DynamicMenuItemStyle" />
            <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="DynamicHoverStyle" />
        </asp:Menu>        
    </td>
</tr>

 <tr>

    <td>

    content here.
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <%--Footer would be provided here--%>
    <td >
    footer here



    </td>
 </tr>

</table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the website is the same website which i had mentioned in my previous questions :

1. [Styling a data drive menu control in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288836/styling-a-data-drive-menu-control-in-asp-net)
2. [Issue in creating a data driven menu in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269261/issue-in-creating-a-data-driven-menu-in-asp-net)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What's your question? Also I'd strongly advice you to not use tables for design layout.

Comment: I question an advice for how to design a website which look like one in http://bayyinah.com/dream./ If any one like to help. I would oblige.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for general advice then Stack Overflow is the wrong place to look. I suggest that you check out the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) to determine what kind of questions to ask.

That being said, I do have some advice for you. I would ditch IE8 for development. Learn to develop on Chrome (or Firefox with Firebug) and then see if it works on other browsers. At the rate that IE8 is dropping, it will only be a concern for another year or two. Since it seems that you're learning web development for fun or a hobby, I don't think it's worth the pain. You can bring up the developer tool in Chrome by hitting F12. Learn to use these kinds of tools.

As for web forms, they can sometimes be difficult to handle. Learning the MVC architecture will help you loads to know how to program web sites. That's not to say you won't encounter web forms in the workplace. I personally rarely deal with web forms.

It seems that you're having problems understanding CSS. I suggest that you learn about the Box Model. [The Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com) are great resources to get you started. Don't be surprised if w3schools sometimes gives you bad advice. It helped me learn a great deal when I was starting out but it's not a place to go to for best practices.

If anyone else has any more advice to add feel free. I'm still a novice in my Senior year at College. Also feel free to correct me.