# Flatten Treeview Nodes collection to List without recursion

Tags: vb.net, linq, treeview

Hopefully this is not a repeat question.  I looked and found similar questions but not sufficient in this case.
I have many tree view controls, and can traverse the Nodes recursively for various reasons.
However, I often need to ***traverse the Nodes as if they are in a List.***
I would like to make a function that creates a `Generic.List(of TreeNode)` from the Nodes collection, **without recursion** if at all possible.

(***Without recursion purely for the exercise of doing it without recursion*** - I understand it *may* not be possible)

This function would save alot of time with repeated use across a massive solution, where the coders could use a simple `For Each` paradigm to traverse the Nodes.

I have seen a technique to 'flatten' the Nodes collection using C#, which uses LINQ and recursion, but I am not sure that the syntax can be converted to VB.NET cleanly.  So if there are any clever VB functions out there can that I can mold to this task - would be very helpful.

There are many similar questions and very informative answers on SO, like this one:
[Enumerating Collections that are not inherently IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815497/enumerating-collections-that-are-not-inherently-ienumerable?rq=1)
...which highlights stack overflow errors in very deep trees using some algorithms.  I hope that a method that does not use recursion will not suffer from Stack overflow errors - however, I am prepared that it might be long and clumsy and slow.

I am also prepared for the answer that '*It is not possible to do this without recursion*'.  However, I would like to confirm or deny this claim using the power of SO (this forum)

Comment: You say you already know how to read through the `TreeView` control to find all the nodes, so why can't you just build a list with the results?  It's not clear what part of the task you are having trouble with.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Thanks, yes I can traverse and build a List using recursion.  The question is supposed to highlight 'no recursion' - if at all possible.

Comment: In which order do you want the items in the list to be in?

Comment: @the_lotus .. I had not considered the order.  For this exercise, the order does not matter.

Comment: That's much more clear now.  Thanks for clarifying your question.  Unfortunately I got pulled away from my desk and others beat me to it :)

Comment: @StevenDoggart Thanks anyway, there are some quick responders here. By the looks of it - there are many effective answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, and not very hard at all....

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TreeView1.ExpandAll()
        For Each TN As TreeNode In TreeView1.NodesToListWithoutRecursionBecauseWhyNot(TraverseType.BreadthFirst)
            Debug.Print(TN.Text)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class

Public Module Extensions

    Public Enum TraverseType
        BreadthFirst
        DepthFirst
    End Enum

    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function NodesToListWithoutRecursionBecauseWhyNot(ByVal TV As TreeView, Optional ByVal Traverse As TraverseType = TraverseType.DepthFirst) As List(Of TreeNode)
        Dim nodes As New List(Of TreeNode)

        Select Case Traverse
            Case TraverseType.BreadthFirst
                Dim Q As New Queue(Of TreeNode)
                For Each TN As TreeNode In TV.Nodes
                    Q.Enqueue(TN)
                Next

                While Q.Count > 0
                    Dim TN As TreeNode = Q.Dequeue
                    nodes.Add(TN)
                    For Each subTN As TreeNode In TN.Nodes
                        Q.Enqueue(subTN)
                    Next
                End While

            Case TraverseType.DepthFirst
                Dim L As New List(Of TreeNode)
                For Each TN As TreeNode In TV.Nodes
                    L.Add(TN)
                Next

                While L.Count > 0
                    Dim TN As TreeNode = L.Item(0)
                    L.RemoveAt(0)
                    nodes.Add(TN)
                    For i As Integer = TN.Nodes.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                        L.Insert(0, TN.Nodes(i))
                    Next
                End While
        End Select

        Return nodes
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Very nice.  Not as clumsy as I expected!

Comment: LOL, I like your improvement and added usefulness. (LOL as you seem like a coder who loves to extend to make a truly powerful feature)

Answer (score 1):

Just add the nodes to the list but at the same time keep the position of the last node you processed. A node is considered process when its immediate children are added to the list.

```
Public Function GetAllNodes(ByVal topNode As TreeNode)

    Dim allNodes As New List(Of TreeNode)
    Dim lastProcessPosition As Integer = 0

    allNodes.Add(topNode)

    Do While lastProcessPosition < allNodes.Count
        allNodes.AddRange(allNodes(lastProcessPosition).Nodes)

        lastProcessPosition += 1
    Loop

    Return allNodes
End Function
```

If you don't have a top node then just substitute the parameter for a list of nodes to start with.

```
Public Function GetAllNodes(ByVal topNodes As TreeNodeCollection)

    Dim allNodes As New List(Of TreeNode)
    Dim lastProcessPosition As Integer = 0

    allNodes.AddRange(topNodes)

    Do While lastProcessPosition < allNodes.Count
        allNodes.AddRange(allNodes(lastProcessPosition).Nodes)

        lastProcessPosition += 1
    Loop

    Return allNodes
End Function
```

I'm not sure if a check for Nothing must be done on the Nodes property before using it.

Note: I was able to remove this for loop and replace it with AddRange

```
'For Each node As TreeNode In allNodes(lastProcessPosition).Nodes
'    allNodes.Add(node)
'Next
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks very tidy too.  Gimme a few secs to test it, but it looks very nice

Comment: @Grantly I removed the For Each and replaced it with AddRange

Comment: Nice improvement. Cheers.  Very effective and neat