# Is it possible to read the internal CPU tick counter from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I have a multithreaded C# program where I need to log how many ticks each thread spends in a specific spin wait lock.

I know there are methods for doing that from C or assembler, but is it possible from to access the same counter directly from C# in some way, that is, without going through the Stopwatch class (I assume calling Start/Stop on that has some overhead, and I am not sure how precise it is)?

Comment: Why do you care how long the spin-wait takes?  They have to be tuned, you can't come up with an ideal number of nanoseconds up front.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before you "rule out" using System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch : does your test system support high-resolution stopwatch ? : see [MSDN on 'StopWatch : check-out : 'Frequency and 'IsHighResolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution.aspx).

Excellent SO thread on getting the "best" out of StopWatch : [SO thread don't miss comments by Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507405/c-is-this-benchmarking-class-accurate)

Precision vs. accuracy in .net time measurement : [SO thread : Precision vs. accuracy in .NET time measurement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394020/stopwatch-accuracy) may be helpful.

"Cost" of API calls in C# to Win32 APIs : QueryPerformanceFrequency and QueryPerformanceCounter : compared to StopWatch ?

One API example from C# here on Codeproject : [2006 code, author in a comment says he did not consider thread safety](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CS_Stopwatch.aspx)

Other threads here on SO have dealt with issues like compensating for the one-time JIT hit of managed code ("dry run" warm-up technique), forcing Garbage Collection, and Finalizers, etc. Easy to find.

Answer (score 4):

You could use QueryPerformanceCounter and QueryPerformenceFrequency.
You can find an example [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/803908d2-ab13-4b90-9d73-6c940e70d9bd/csharp-StopWatch-Class.aspx).

[System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) should be a high-perfomance counter.
However, it it not present in Compact Framework but the above solution fixes that problem.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class which is based upon *QueryPerformance** APIs is precisely for this purpose.

MSDN:

> The Stopwatch class assists the
>   manipulation of timing-related
>   performance counters within managed
>   code. Specifically, the Frequency
>   field and GetTimestamp method can be
>   used in place of the unmanaged Win32
>   APIs QueryPerformanceFrequency and
>   QueryPerformanceCounter.

Also [results collected by Kristof Verbiest](http://kristofverbiest.blogspot.com/2008/10/beware-of-stopwatch.html) is worth a glipse.